# How to generate QR-Code with iCalender in It?

Tags: php, .net, mobile, icalendar, qr-code

I want to generate QR-Codes that are added to the calendar on a mobile phone. I know that it is possible because [this online gernerator](http://keremerkan.net/qr-code-and-2d-code-generator/) generates iCalender QR-Codes that work perfekt.

I tried it with an ics file as input but it only crashed my android barcode scanner :-)
An example in any programming language would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/BarcodeContents or http://www.qr-barcodes.com/data-formats/ for a explanation of the different QR barcode data formats.

Without seeing your actual iCalender file, it's nearly impossible to know what's probably going on. Most likely you simply have to remove the `BEGIN:VCALENDAR` / `END:VCALENDAR` start/end elements as described on the page above.

Comment: Thanks! By removing BEGIN:VCALENDAR / END:VCALENDAR everything works now.